# How to place MySQL row data in the URL?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic

I want to create a dynamic PHP page where for every MySQL row there's a different page.

Every entry will have a unique identifier that I want to place in the URL and that's what I don't know how to do.

EXAMPLE: stackoverflow.com(look at the numbers in the url)

Comment: That's called parameters. Have a good search :)

Comment: You should really do your homework. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help first and then dive into some good tutorials for programming, buy books. Good luck.

Comment: Gave a clearer example now so everyone knows what I mean and this can be flagged as not being off-topic. Also I'd like for the data to not be put there using GET just because it's the page where a form is being submitted that I'm working on just like stackoverflow works I imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your database connection with PDO and $conn being your connection string:

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM table');
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo '<a href="page.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Page Link</a>';
}
```

This will display a link to a page with the id variable being set by the id field coming from the database.  Assuming there are no additional WHERE clauses and you wish to display all links where there are entires in the database.  If you just wish to display one entry, add an additional WHERE clause to the query and restructure the foreach to a general query.  I think this is what you were asking for, I'll edit/clarify if not.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Change `echo '<a href=\"page.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Page Link</a>"';` to `echo '<a href="page.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Page Link</a>';` otherwise the generated URL will not contain correct syntax. Do test your answer before posting; I always do ;-)

Comment: You edited your answer, yet just not with my **FULL** recommendation; this will fail. I give up.

Comment: Is there any way to hide the '?id=' part and just have it be website.com/idNumber/ ?

Comment: If the pages exist (website.com/3/ or wesite.com/4/), you could edit the echo statement to: echo '<a href="/' . $row['id'] . '">Page Link</a>';  This will change the target to a url with the id as the name.  an .htaccess (if on apache) edit would be in order as well.  Or, you could concatenate to: echo '<a href="/' . $row['id'] . '.php">Page Link</a>'; if you do not have access to .htaccess (if apache is the web server).

Comment: Would this work if the page was not created before?

Comment: No.  The page would have to exist prior to linking over to it.

Comment: Then do you know how to generate the page automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Set up one column in the table as an integer that auto-increments (using the AUTO_INCREMENT argument when creating the table). Then, when you insert data into the table, don't pass through a value for that field and it will be generated for you.

That column should probably also be the primary key of the table, since it's used to uniquely identify items.

This is the kind of SQL you would need to create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Then just use the `id` column to refer to the data - a typical query might be `SELECT * FROM animals WHERE id = 1;`

EDIT: I note that you want to have more human-readable URLs, like `/page/1/`. That can be done using plain old PHP, but using a proper MVC framework will make it much, much easier.